# customize actionbar android who new playstore style

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to help me customize my actionbar, I am using a navigation drawer and would like to have the option when you open the action bar is dark.

I also would like to know how to customize a imageview to take a photo and move the name to the right and playstore.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

**EDIT**

I solved

```
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerMenu, R.drawable.ic_drawer,          R.string.texto_menu_opciones, R.string.texto_lineas_transporte){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(listaOpciones.get(position).getNombre());
                getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_solid_cvbus));
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                //getActionBar().setTitle("Opciones");
                getActionBar().setTitle(listaOpciones.get(position).getNombre());
                getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_transparent_cvbus));
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) 
            {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put this code for changing the actionbar color

```
ActionBar ac= getActionBar();
    ac.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000"))); // #000000 - for black
```

put this code in the drawer opening method..